# How to get old position of snake body parts in Java

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

I will try my best to explain the issue. So basically I have come to the point in my snake game which I feared the most - the array. So I what I have done is an ArrayList full of Rectangles.

I then add a Rectangle each time I eat the food and I am now at the "looping" part where I have to loop the different rectangles.

I succeded with adding one rectangle to the snake - I just took the old `head.x` location and the `head.y` location and but it into the `snakeParts.get(0).setLocation`.

The problem I am having is drawing the rest of the array (which would be index nr 1 to infinity).

I can't seem to get the rest of the ArrayLists's old positions. For example: I want `snakeParts.get(1)` to get `snakeParts.get(0)`'s old position but I can't seem to figure out how to do that logic. I wonder if any of you could give me a hand?

Here is the part of the code that is affected:

```
repaint();
//Test
for(int z = 0; z < snakeParts.size(); z++) {
    System.out.println(z); //Test printing
    if(z == 0) {
        snakeParts.get(z).setLocation(head.x, head.y); //Printing index 0   
    }
    else {
    snakeParts.get(z).setLocation(snakeParts.get(z - 1).getLocation()); 
    //Takes all the indexes and puts them where the snakeParts.get(0) is. I want them to get longer - like the Snake game
    }
    //Loop different might solve the issue?     
}
head.x += speedx;
head.y += speedy;
```

I am doing this in JPanel and my `ArrayList` is an array of the Rectangle class which can be found here: [Rectangle Class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Rectangle.html)

If you want the entire code - please ask! I thought it would be easier to just show you guys this code sample because it's the only part that affects what I am trying to achieve.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start from the end and go towards the head, get last part, set its position to where last-1 is.
Then go, for last-1, set its position to where last-2 is.
Repeat that until you reach second part, once you set its position to head, then move your head.

Edit.
Here is how does forward vs backward loop look like:

```
for(int z = 0; z < snakeParts.size(); z++) {}

for(int z = snakeParts.size() - 1; z >= 0; z--){}
```

First one starts at 0, goes to size of snake parts by increases of 1.
Second one starts at size of snakeparts - 1 (we decrease by 1 because snakeParts are counted from 0, not from 1), works as long as z is greater-equal to 0, and at each step it reduces z by 1.
Hope that helps :)
In your code you should make sure you are not trying to access indices smaller or larger than the array.

Comment: How do I write a backwards loop? I get IndexOutOfBounds error..